# If the intersection of two sets is subset of set S then the union of them is also a subset of S. How is this is formulated with simple words?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this implication:

$$((A ∩ B) \subseteq S) \to (( A ∪ B) \subseteq S)$$

How can I express this with simple and a few words?

By simple I mean not the scientific translation of the expression.

My guess is that it should be translated as all the elements of $A$ and $B$ are contained in $S$, but that seems too simple...

Comment: That's not even a true statement...

Comment: I know I just need the meaning of that.

Comment: "If everything which is in both of the sets $A$ and $B$ belongs to $S,$ then everything which is in even one of them belongs to $S.$"

Comment: By the way, *subset* is one word; *sub* by itself is a prefix, not a word, except when used as a shortened form of "submarine" or "substitute".

Comment: Yes that seems right but still a little bit off of everyday speech, also thanks for the extra info!